# Uniform updating

Tags: bayesian, uniform-distribution

I have a uniform prior with certain values $a$ and $b$ (not standard uniform). How do I update this distribution to take into account the results from my data? If it was $U(0,1)$, I could convert it to a beta distribution, but since it is not, I'm not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Can you simply normalize your data first? It's just a linear transformation, I should think it wouldn't have any effect, & you could back-transform it afterwards.

Comment: Are you trying to update the parameters $a$ and $b$?  If you're trying to update some parameter $\theta \sim \text{U}(a,b)$, I agree with @gung - you can just update a parameter $\phi = (\theta - a)/(b-a)$ where the prior on $\phi$ is a $\beta(1,1)$.

Comment: @jbowman, could you please explain where your formula for $\phi$ comes from?

Comment: I'm just transforming $\theta$ to a $\text{U}(0,1)$ variate; that variate is $\phi$.  Subtracting $a$ makes the lower bound on $\phi = 0$, dividing by $b-a$ makes the range (and hence the upper bound) equal $1$.

Answer (score 1):

A uniform prior will not alter the form of the likelihood, but if the likelihood is otherwise defined outside (a,b), then the prior will truncate the likelihood to that interval (making the posterior zero outside the interval).

Inside the interval the likelihood will simply be scaled by a constant.

[image]